# How to work out 95% confidence interval from odds ratio and standard error

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis

$lnOR = -0.909 - (-1.707) = 0.798$ and its standard error is $SE(lnOR) = \sqrt{0.2182 + 0.3182} = 0.386$. The results of the adjusted indirect comparison suggest that x was less effective than y for (odds ratio $2.22$; 95% CI: $1.04, 4.72$).

How was the the confidence interval worked out in that example?

Comment: Note: $\sqrt{0.2182 + 0.3182} \ne 0.386$. The $0.386$ appears to be correct (since it yields the correct CI bounds), but something is off with the square-root part.

Comment: Can you explain what the numbers in your post refer to?

Comment: @wolfgang I think each one should have been squared first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CI was computed with $$\exp[0.798 \pm 1.96 \times 0.386] = (1.04, 4.73)$$ (the discrepancy between the 4.72 and the 4.73 is due to rounding error).

Comment: Thank you, can you please tell me what a wide CI accompanying RR can indicate in a meta-analysis of trials? Would the inclusion of fewer studies in a meta-analysis yield wider CIs?

Comment: It indicates that the parameter that is being estimated is estimated impressively. More studies will tend to lead to more precise estimates and hence a tighter CI (unless the addition of the studies introduces additional heterogeneity).

Comment: By the way, you talk about the RR (also in the title before I edited it) but the value you posted is a (log) odds ratio and not a (log) risk ratio. Different things.

Comment: Yes, I am carrying out a meta-analysis to estimate RR using Bucher's method. The above example was one I found on the net to help me implement it into my own analysis. However, the result I got has an extremely wide confidence interval (0.2 to 12.2) making me wonder where I am going wrong.

Comment: How can one work out SE from given a confidence intervals?